# validate regex inside XML synthetic.xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following synthetic.xml file and need to validate user input using regex.

```
<synthetic xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://www.xebialabs.com/deployit/synthetic"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xebialabs.com/deployit/synthetic synthetic.xsd">
    
        <type type="keyCreation.Streams" extends="xlrelease.PythonScript">
            <property name="taskColor" hidden="true" default="#00b0ff" />
            <property name="scriptLocation" hidden="true" default="tasks/key_creation.py"/>
    
            <property name="PACKAGE_NAME" label="Package Name" category="input"  description="Package NAME"  required="true"/>
       </type>
</synthetic>
```

I need to evaluate the package_name as follows in the xml file
regex  validation of the user input

```
"^(data|products|etl)-[0-9a-z-]+$"
```

How can i add regex validation to the property name = PACKAGE_NAME

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky. Its using the following XSD. https://github.com/amitmohleji/xebialabs-sampledar/blob/master/synthetic.xsd, my input is the above synthetic.xml (so PACKAGE_NAME) should only accept the defined regex pattern. Don't know how to add the validation rule in synthetic.xml. thanks.